# Playsound() in C playing windows error sound, I have included -lwinmm linker

Tags: c, playsound

I'm trying to use PlaySound() in C.

I've check everything but I always get the default windows error sound.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\Music\\hoatau.wav"),NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

I had add -lwinmm in linker of compiler. Full location and just name of sound file has been tested. I'm using DevC/C++ and compiling with C.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `SND_FILENAME` flag?

Comment: As @SergejChristoforov said **you must use flag `SND_FILENAME`** to specify that the first parameter is a file name. Before you use any function you are expected to have read and understood how it works. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)

Comment: I have try using `SND_FILENAME` with this, but it's still playing window error sound!

Comment: Documentation says:"If the function cannot find the specified sound and the SND_NODEFAULT flag is not specified, PlaySound uses the default system event sound instead.". Add the flag `SND_NODEFAULT`, and check the return value. If you hear no sound and get `FALSE` return value the filename is wrong. Anyway no more help can be given without a sample of your code because there can be another error elsewhere.

Comment: Just a detail, **the function fails only if no sound file can be found**. Meaning not the file you specified nor the default system sound, in all other cases returns always `TRUE`. Pratically don't expect to have a failure... P.S. It works as I explained (I have tested it).

Comment: Thank you! But I have check and it return 1 though PlaySound is dumb when I add `SND_NODEFAULT`.

Comment: Read my previous comment: **it fails only if it can't even find the default sound :(**. Anyway your problem is the file. The path is wrong or the file is corrupted.

Comment: I had use `system("hoatau.wav" );` command to check and the file's not corrupted, it open wav file then playing the sound. And I also check use PlaySound with system sound but it still playing window error sound.

Comment: Hard to say anything more. The function works, the only problem could be the wrong path. You have to check compiler warnings, i.e. maybe you're passing ANSI string for filename in a UNICODE compilation or the like. What's sure is that the filename is wrong.

Comment: The compiler not warnings. When I F11, it's just run and playing window error sound.